# Bokeh CheckBoxGroupButton

Tags: python, checkbox, bokeh

I'm building a chart using `bokeh`. In this chart, I'm inserting a CheckBoxButtonGroup.
I'm using this code:

```
 LABELS = [" Produzione " + postazione + " " + stazione + " ",
              " Cycle time " + postazione + " " + stazione+ " ",
              " Scarti " + postazione + " " + stazione+ " ",
              " Avarie " + postazione + " " + stazione2+ " ",
              " Stati " + postazione + " "]
 checkbox_button_group = CheckboxButtonGroup(labels=LABELS, active=[0,0,0,0,0])
```

With this code, I thought to display the 5 checkbox buttons no flagged.
But if I try to render the page I can see this situation:

[image]

As you can see the first option is every time selected. It is possible to display at the first time all options no selected?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default or pass an empty list to the value `active=[]` in CheckboxButtonGroup.

```python
CheckboxButtonGroup(labels=LABELS)
# or
CheckboxButtonGroup(labels=LABELS, active=[])
```

[image: CheckboxGroup default]

For a better understanding. `active=[0]` sets the box at possition `0` to active. `active=[1,4]` sets two boxes to active at possition 1 and 4.
This is the output:

[image: CheckboxGroup active=[1,4]]